# Getting all of the url in Go

Tags: go

I would like to create a function which print the name of the url.
It is not working when the url has a '?' character.

Thank you for your help

```
func lang(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        message := r.URL.Path
        w.Write([]byte(message))
}
```

Comment: please read all the comments in below answer - you are missing an action it suggests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Request.RequestURI](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.RequestURI) to get the request URI.

```
func lang(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        message := r.RequestURI
        w.Write([]byte(message))
}
```

Comment: [RequestURI](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.RequestURI) is a `string` which has no `Get` method.

Comment: It works like a charm !
Thank you very much, you gave me the answer very quickly

Comment: @Victor if this post answered your question, consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so that others can find it in the future.

Comment: @HenryWoody I have just done this. 
I am still a newby in stackoverflow, thank you for your comment